# grep cannot find all occurrences of a substring in a very big file

Tags: bash, file, grep, substring

I am on a Ubuntu OS, in a Bash shell, trying to use `grep` to find all occurrences of substring `engineBreakdown()` inside a .tra extention log file, let's say `my_log_16.tra`, and save the results inside a file, let's say `results_16.txt`

So I run

```
cat /path/to/my_log_16.tra | grep "engineBreakdown()" > results_16.txt
```

and when I run `less results_16.txt` I actually see that there inside are saved some lines containing the substring, but they are not all the lines I expected.

In fact, when I manually search the occurrences of `engineBreakdown()` down `my_log_16.tra`, I see that there are other lines containing the substring, but these are not saved into `results_16.txt`. So it seems that my command only saves the first occurrences of the substring.

I think the grep may fail because `my_log_16.tra` is a very large file ( about 100 MB ).

If this is the cause, is there a more reliable way to find all occurrences of a substring in a very big file?

### version and alias of grep

```
grep --version
```

> ```
> grep (GNU grep) 2.25
> Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.     
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.     
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.     
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.         
>
> Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
> ```

```
$ type -a grep
```

> ```
> grep is aliased to `grep --color=auto'
> grep is /bin/grep
> ```

### Example of lines from my_log_16.tra

lines correctly detected and saved into results_16.txt

```
[I 2022-10-16 07:26:35.449 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-16 07:26:35.846 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-16 07:26:35.848 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
```

a piece of the file where the substring appears, but it is not saved into results_16.txt

```
[I 2022-10-16 11:32:48.039 web:2064] 200 GET /static/ui-src/default/img/Customer.png?v=0.9702853857687699 (127.0.0.1) 10.49ms
[I 2022-10-16 11:32:49.778 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-16 11:32:50.122 websocketclient:62] Connection : url::ws://localhost:3333/ws
[I 2022-10-16 11:32:50.125 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-16 11:32:50.128 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-16 11:32:55.123 websocketclient:62] Connection : url::ws://localhost:3333/ws
[I 2022-10-16 11:32:55.128 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-16 11:32:55.134 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
```

another piece of the file where the substring appears, but it is not saved into results_16.txt

```
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:35.127 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:35.138 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:39.206 websocketclient:62] Connection : url::ws://127.0.0.1:9999/request
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:39.220 websocketclient:62] Connection : url::ws://127.0.0.1:9999/auxiliary
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:39.228 channels:75] _on_connection_error, host=127.0.0.1, port=9999
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:39.233 channels:82] _on_connection_close, host=127.0.0.1, port=9999
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:39.237 channels:75] _on_connection_error, host=127.0.0.1, port=9999
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:39.243 channels:82] _on_connection_close, host=127.0.0.1, port=9999
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:40.122 websocketclient:62] Connection : url::ws://localhost:3333/ws
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:40.128 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:40.133 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:44.206 websocketclient:62] Connection : url::ws://127.0.0.1:9999/request
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:44.221 websocketclient:62] Connection : url::ws://127.0.0.1:9999/auxiliary
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:44.227 channels:75] _on_connection_error, host=127.0.0.1, port=9999
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:44.232 channels:82] _on_connection_close, host=127.0.0.1, port=9999
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:44.234 channels:75] _on_connection_error, host=127.0.0.1, port=9999
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:44.237 channels:82] _on_connection_close, host=127.0.0.1, port=9999
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:45.122 websocketclient:62] Connection : url::ws://localhost:3333/ws
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:45.126 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
[I 2022-10-17 04:00:45.128 Rservice:75] engineBreakdown()
```

### update 1

I also tryed with

```
grep "engineBreakdown()" /path/to/my_log_16.tra > results_16.txt
```

but the result is the same.

### update 2

As suggested, double quotes might not be enough to handle the parentheses properly, so I removed the parentheses from the input substring and changed the double quotes to single ones

```
grep "engineBreakdown" /path/to/my_log_16.tra > results_16.txt

grep 'engineBreakdown' /path/to/my_log_16.tra > results_16.txt
```

but the result is the same.

Comment: If the same string occurs multiple times in the same line, grep will only output a single line. If such lines are long and wrapped, they may appears as multiple lines when opening the file in a text editor.

Comment: Useless use of cat: `grep "engineBreakdown()" /path/to/my_log_16.tra > results_16.txt`.

Comment: The double quotes might not be enough to handle the parentheses properly. Try with single quotes and/or escape the parentheses.

Comment: 100 MB is hardly a big file. Can you post some lines that are present in the input file but weren't saved in the output file?

Comment: Is the file completely text? Or could there be NUL characters in some lines?

Comment: Yeah, `file /path/to/my_log_16.tra` could be interesting

Comment: @9769953 how can I detect if there are some NUL characters in some lines ? Do you mean these characters could be interpreted as an "end of file" by Bash ?

Comment: Unsurprisingly, grep finds all lines containing the pattern, with and without parentheses, if I just copy your text and paste it in a file.

Comment: If you are really stuck: **Create the smallest file that reproduces the error (probably by repeatedly splitting the file in half, preserving the half that contains unrecognized lines) and upload it to google drive or wherever we have access.** Verify that if you download it and grep it, the lines are still not detected.

Comment: May be your `grep` command has some issue? What happens if you use `sed -n '/engineBreakdown()/p' /path/to/my_log_16.tra > op.txt` ?

Comment: Chances are you'll detect an anomaly with the file already in that process. Whatever the case, I suppose we need the original file.

Comment: Oh, true, @Sundeep  is right: Please do a `grep --version` or whatever produces a version string with your grep and post it here.

Comment: @Sundeep `sed -n '/engineBreakdown()/p' /path/to/my_log_16.tra > op.txt` does exactly what I was trying to achieve via grep. Thanks! Type it as answer and I will flag it as the solution.

Comment: I'd want to verify the version of `grep` being used as well as rule out an alias or function; what does `type -a grep` return?

Comment: @markp-fuso i have added the info in paragraph "version and alias of grep"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try if this `awk` helps.

##### Data

```
$ cat file
engineBreakdown()
engineBreakdown() engineBreakdown() engineBreakdown() engineBreakdown()
engineBreakdown()
```

```
$ awk -v var="engineBreakdown()" '
    $0~var{
      printf NR
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i~var){x++}
      }
      print " # matches: " x
      x=0
  }' file
1 # matches: 1
2 # matches: 4
3 # matches: 1
```

Just printing the lines (like grep) without substring detection simply do

```
$ awk -v var="engineBreakdown()" '$0~var{ print }' file
engineBreakdown()
engineBreakdown() engineBreakdown() engineBreakdown() engineBreakdown()
engineBreakdown()
```

Comment: yes! This correctly detects all the line in which the substring appears.
Now, how to have the entire line printed -as `grep` would do- instead of `<line number> # matches: <number of occurrences of the substring in the line>` ?

Comment: @Tms91 See edit. It leaves out the whole substring part.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your `grep` command is behaving oddly (perhaps because you are using an old version that has some bug that was fixed later).

Here's an alternative with `sed`:

```bash
sed -n '/engineBreakdown()/p' /path/to/my_log_16.tra > op.txt
```

I'd recommend updating your `grep` installation. [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) is another alternative.

Comment: Thanks! this answer is correct, I just want to give the point to @Andre Wildberg because he was quicker in understanding the problem lied in using grep.